# Is this a kernel panic?

Tags: 10.10, boot, kernel

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

what's the meaning of all that mess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's what's known as a "[kernel oops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_oops)," a superset of kernel panics. If this is a new installation of Ubuntu, the problem is most likely due to corruption of the installation media.

If it's not a new installation, try loading an older kernel by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot to access Grub's boot menu. If that starts up alright, you can report a bug by running `ubuntu-bug linux-image-2.6.35-24-generic`.

Comment: uhmm soo, is it a bad thing if it's not a new installation?